# ember-data stores a string instead of a number

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my ember app I want to reuse a model attribute as soon as the form is submitted. But the store seems to keep it as string unless I reload the whole route. I am using [this](https://github.com/genkgo/ember-localforage-adapter) and the following components:

```
Ember      : 1.12.0
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.18
jQuery     : 1.11.3
```

**/app/models/purchase.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  amount: DS.attr('number'),
  createdAt: DS.attr('date', {
    defaultValue: function() { return new Date(); }
  }),

  .. other callback and associations..
});
```

**/app/controllers/ledger/purchases/new.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return {
      newPurchase: this.store.createRecord('purchase', {
        name: null,
        amount: null,
        player: null
      })
    }
  }
});
```

**/app/templates/ledger/purchases/new.hbs**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h4>New purchase</h4>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="sr-only control-label">name</label>
        {{input id='name' type="text" value=newPurchase.name placeholder="What" class="form-control"}}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="amount" class="sr-only control-label">amount</label>
        {{input id='amount' type='number' value=newPurchase.amount placeholder="How much" class="form-control"}}
      </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" {{action "create"}}>create</button>
        {{#link-to 'ledger.purchases' tagName="button" class="btn btn-link" }}cancel{{/link-to}}
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**/app/controllers/ledger/purchases/new.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  newPurchase: Ember.computed.alias('model.newPurchase'),

  actions: {
    create: function() {
      var np = this.get('newPurchase');
      console.log(Ember.typeOf(np.get('amount')));
      ........
      save np etc...
    }
  }
});
```

the console log call clearly shows that the type is a `string`. The ember inspector shows the same. However data are correctly saved to the backend because after reloading everything is fine. But I need the amount as a number as soon as it is submitted because I use it to make and show the sum of all purchases.

Comment: Where's your `purchase` model definition?

Comment: What's the response of server when you `POST` purchase?

Comment: the fact is that i am using [this](https://github.com/genkgo/ember-localforage-adapter) which don't let me debug that side. But It is saved and even reloaded correctly (included the amount attribute, the store show a number). But even without saving I didn't expect to get a string.. what if I want to numerically check that value before saving for example?

Comment: I think you'd need to `parseFloat` any time you want to use this value.

Comment: tried `parseFloat` before saving `var npAmount = np.get('amount');  np.set('amount', parseFloat(npAmount, 10));` and it works but it makes me feel so unconfident. Why if I declare an attribute everywhere I need to convert it manually before saving??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I know what's going on. Setting input type to number won't help here. Value is still recognized as string. Usually when you submit form, backend anyway returns this value formatted as a number and problem's gone. You can see this even when you mock your data with a number, without a backend.

My solution would be to use a computed property for input component. Model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  amount: DS.attr('number'),
  createdAt: DS.attr('date', {
    defaultValue: function() { return new Date(); }
  }),

  amountAsNum: Ember.computed('amount', {
    get: function () {
      return parseFloat(this.get('amount'));
    },
    set: function (key, value) {
      var valueToSet = parseFloat(value);
      this.set('amount', valueToSet);
      return valueToSet;
    }
}),

  .. other callback and associations..
});
```

Template:

```
{{input id='amount' type='number' value=newPurchase.amountAsNum placeholder="How much" class="form-control"}}
```

Now, you can check `typeof(amount)` before save and it'll give you `number`. [Demo on JS Bin.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wukeqajuyu/2/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Daniel, many thanks for your time. I am going to use and accept your solution even if I am not fully satisfied. Coming from Rails many solutions seem just workarounds in the Ember world. But it's ok.. I'm a newbie, Ember is young and lastly the usage of ember-local-adapter makes the famous learning curve even steeper for me.